# Swagger-spray adds extraneous parameters

Tags: scala, swagger, spray

I'm Switching from spray-swagger to swagger-spray in order to get swagger2.0 generated, and I'm encountering the following problem: swagger-spray automatically adds parameters of type 'body', in addition to the manually specified @ApiImplicitParams, for all actual function params.

Annotated code:

```
@Path("areas/{areaId}/items/{itemId}")
@ApiOperation("Retrieves an item from an area by id", httpMethod = "GET", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
@ApiImplicitParams(Array(
  new ApiImplicitParam(name = "areaId", paramType = "path", required = true, dataType = "integer", value = "Items area")
  new ApiImplicitParam(name = "itemId", paramType = "path", required = true, dataType = "integer", value = "Item id")
))
def getItem(areaId: Int, itemId: Int) = { ... }
```

The generated swagger contains the following:

```
...
parameters: [
{
  in: "body",
  name: "body",
  required: false,
  schema: {
    type: "integer",
    format: "int64"
  }
},
{
  in: "body",
  name: "body",
  required: false,
  schema: {
    type: "integer",
    format: "int64"
  }
},
{
  name: "areaId",
  in: "path",
  description: "Items area",
  required: true,
  type: "integer"
},
{
  name: "itemId",
  in: "path",
  description: "Item id",
  required: true,
  type: "integer"
} ]
```

Instead of only the last 2. Any idea where these extra params come from / how can I suppress them / what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, yes, IIRC; the trick is to put `@ApiParam(hidden = true)` before each actual function parameter. This way, only your explicit annotations are processed and the default _body_-typed parameters are not created.
I have not found a way to control the swagger generated from the params themselves well enough to replace the explicit function-level annotations, sadly.